# Converting string to byte in go

Tags: go, byte

Basically what I'm trying to do is convert a string in the hexidecimal format to a byte and append the byte to a byte slice.

I've tried:

```
func main() {
    bytes := []byte{0xfc}
    string := "0xe8"
    bytes = append(bytes, string...)
    fmt.Printf("%s", bytes)
}
```

output:

```
�0xe8
```

I know I could just declare a byte variable and append the byte. 
I need to convert the string into a byte.

Expected output:

```
��
```

Comment: Use `strconv.ParseInt`

Comment: Tried: "b, err := strconv.ParseInt(string, 10, 64)" outputed error: "strconv.ParseInt: parsing "0xe8": invalid syntax", Could you provide an example?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on strconv.ParseInt, Justin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is work fo me.

```golang
func main() {
    bytes := []byte{0xfc}
    str := "0xe8"
    pc, _ := strconv.ParseUint(str, 0, 64)

    bytes = append(bytes, uint8(pc))
    fmt.Printf("%s", bytes)
}
```

Output:

��

Comment: @Flimzy ok, i changed my post.

Comment: @AlexeyBril note that there is no need for the prefix trimming, if you pass in `0` as the base `ParseInt` and `ParseUint` will infer the base from the prefix. e.g. [`strconv.ParseUint("0xe8", 0, 64)`](https://play.golang.com/p/3sDNGCTV1M4). From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt): *"If base == 0, the base is implied by the string's prefix: base 2 for "0b", base 8 for "0" or "0o", base 16 for "0x", and base 10 otherwise."*

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I agree, this option will be more optimal. Fixed implementation